# make: glib-compile-resources: Command not found

Tags: linux, glibc

I try to compile a code that uses gtk3 and I get the following error:

`make: glib-compile-resources: Command not found`

I am using fedora. I searched for the file "glib-compile-resources" and it does not exist in my computer.

This file should be included into glib2 (according to: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/glib2/).

I have all these packages installed:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i ^glib
glib-1.2.10-34.fc15.x86_64
glib-networking-2.28.6.1-2.fc15.x86_64
glibmm24-2.28.1-1.fc15.x86_64
glib2-static-2.28.8-1.fc15.x86_64
glibc-utils-2.14.1-6.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.14.1-6.x86_64
glibc-common-2.14.1-6.x86_64
glib-devel-1.2.10-34.fc15.x86_64
glib2-2.28.8-1.fc15.i686
glibc-2.14.1-6.i686
glibc-static-2.14.1-6.x86_64
glib2-devel-2.28.8-1.fc15.x86_64
glib2-2.28.8-1.fc15.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.14.1-6.x86_64
glibc-2.14.1-6.x86_64

rpm -qa | grep -i ^gtk
gtksourceview3-3.0.5-1.fc15.x86_64
gtk2-immodule-xim-2.24.7-3.fc15.x86_64
gtkglext-libs-1.2.0-14.fc15.x86_64
gtk2-2.24.7-3.fc15.x86_64
gtkmm30-3.0.1-1.fc15.x86_64
gtkmm24-2.24.0-3.fc15.x86_64
gtk3-3.0.12-1.fc15.x86_64
gtk2-devel-2.24.7-3.fc15.x86_64
gtk3-immodule-xim-3.0.12-1.fc15.x86_64
gtk+-1.2.10-71.fc15.x86_64
gtk2-engines-2.20.2-2.fc15.x86_64
gtk-vnc2-0.4.3-1.fc15.x86_64
gtk3-devel-3.0.12-1.fc15.x86_64
gtkmm-utils-0.4.1-3.fc15.x86_64
gtkhtml3-4.0.2-1.fc15.x86_64
```

I would like to update glib, but i do not know exactly how to do it. I tried using (yum update glibc-*) but it appears the following:

```
yum update glib-*
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Answer (score 8):

You're missing an asterisk in your yum update command. Also, I'd drop the hyphen:

```
yum update glib*
```

Specifically, `glib-compile-resources` is provided by the `glib2-devel` package (note that you only have `glib-devel` installed).

Output from my Fedora 19 machine:

```
[root@some-machine ~]# yum provides glib-compile-resources
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
glib2-devel-2.36.3-2.fc19.i686 : A library of handy utility functions
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/glib-compile-resources



glib2-devel-2.36.3-2.fc19.x86_64 : A library of handy utility functions
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/glib-compile-resources



glib2-devel-2.36.3-3.fc19.i686 : A library of handy utility functions
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/glib-compile-resources



glib2-devel-2.36.3-3.fc19.x86_64 : A library of handy utility functions
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/glib-compile-resources



glib2-devel-2.36.3-3.fc19.x86_64 : A library of handy utility functions
Repo        : @updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/glib-compile-resources
```

Comment: It seems that I do have glib2-level (look below), then what else can I do?
yum install glib2-devel
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Package glib2-devel-2.28.8-1.fc15.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: I did:
yum uninstall glib2-devel
and then:
yum install glib2-devel

Now I have the glib2-devel library, but still not the glib-compile-resources:

[root@suve ~]# rpm -qa | grep -i ^glib
glib-1.2.10-34.fc15.x86_64
glib-networking-2.28.6.1-2.fc15.x86_64
glibmm24-2.28.1-1.fc15.x86_64
glibc-utils-2.14.1-6.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.14.1-6.x86_64
glibc-common-2.14.1-6.x86_64
glib-devel-1.2.10-34.fc15.x86_64
glib2-2.28.8-1.fc15.i686
glibc-2.14.1-6.i686
glibc-static-2.14.1-6.x86_64
glib2-2.28.8-1.fc15.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.14.1-6.x86_64
glibc-2.14.1-6.x86_64
glib2-devel-2.28.8-1.fc15.x86_64

Comment: You have glib2-2.28. glib-compile-resources was online introduced in glib2-2.31 (see http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/changelogs/glib/2.31.16/changelog.html). The best idea I have for you if upgrading your fedora (15 is pretty outdated...). Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Mureinik, I updated to fedora 17 and now I have the file glib2-2.32.4-2.fc17.x86_64
I installed gtk3-devel to solve some problem but now when I do make it shows:

Comment: Thanks Mureinik I updated to fedora 17 and now I have the file glib2-2.32.4-2.fc17.x86_64
But now it shows:
Building Binary gui_lx9_enet
/bin/ld: ../chip-interfaces/src/MQInterface.o: undefined reference to symbol 'mq_send@@GLIBC_2.3.4'
/bin/ld: note: 'mq_send@@GLIBC_2.3.4' is defined in DSO /lib64/librt.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib64/librt.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [gui_lx9_enet] Error 1

I added /lib64 to PATH and made a symbolic link in /usr/bin, but none of them worked. Any other ideas?

Comment: can you this info to the question (or open another question for it)? It's really hard to read like this in the comments...

Comment: I agree, very uncomfortable this commente. Anyway I managed to solve the problem. I just added the following in the Makefile:
LIBS = -lrt

Thanks for your help